# Is the union of independent events independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $A_1,A_2,....$ are events all independent of an event $B$. Do we also have that $\bigcup_{n\geq1}A_n$ is independent of $B$?

Comment: By "all independent", do you mean that each $A_i$ is pairwise independent of $B$, or that the entire set $A_1,A_2,\ldots,B$ is independent?

Comment: @joriki the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with uniform probability, $B=\{1,2\}$, $A_1=\{1,3\}$, $A_2=\{1,4\}$.

We have $P(B)=P(A_1)=P(A_2)=\frac12$ and $P(B\cap A_1)=P(B\cap A_2)=\frac14$, so $B$ is pairwise independent with both $A_1$ and $A_2$. However $P(A_1\cup A_2)=\frac34$ and $P(B\cap(A_1\cup A_2))=\frac14$, so $B$ is not independent of $A_1\cup A_2$.

In case you require to have an event $A_n$ for all $n\geq1$, you can simply take $A_n=A_2$ for $n\geq2$.

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in the comments, the question is whether $\bigcup_nA_n$ is necessarily independent of $B$ if each of the $A_i$ is pairwise independent of $B$.

This is not the case. Consider $A_1$ and $A_2$ independent events, each with probability $\frac12$ (e.g. the results two independent fair coin tosses) and $B=\left(A_1\cap\overline{A_2}\right)\cup\left(\overline{A_1}\cap A_2\right)$, the symmetric difference of $A_1$ and $A_2$. (If you think of $A_1$ and $A_2$ as random bits, then $B$ is their XOR.) Both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are pairwise independent of $B$, but $P(B\cap(A_1\cup A_2))=P(B)\ne P(B)\cdot P(A_1\cup A_2)$.

Comment: Would this change if the sets $A_n$ where increasing, so $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$

Comment: For a finite sequence, that would trivially imply independence, since the union would just be the largest set. For an infinite sequence, it also implies independence. Proof sketch: Consider the disjoint differences $A_{n+1}\setminus A_n$ (with $A_0=\emptyset$). These are also pairwise independent of $B$. By countable additivity, the probability of their union (which is the union of the $A_n$) is the sum of their probabilities; and the same is true for their intersections with $B$ (which are also disjoint); so we can take the limit of the multiplicative property that defines independence.